# Track changes in a sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to know if there's an event or function in VBA other than `Worksheet_Change` that follows changes in a sheet because `Worksheet_Change` is an event that gives me an immediate response and I want a function/event that would give me a result when I ask for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a option in  excel to show track changes don't know much about VBA codes  but finded some links  may be one of those work for you

You can create macro

I think there is no such function we have to create it

You can see following VBA codes links may be you find some function that works for you

[Track Changes Automatically in Worksheet with VBA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/track-changes-automatically-in-worksheet-with-vba/%3Famp&ved=2ahUKEwijkKe_k-DnAhU9ILcAHUYBCMAQFjACegQIDxAO&usg=AOvVaw0BPOXTvuuO3Biyu7NnwPPY&ampcf=1&cshid=1582203532202)

[VBA code to track changes in workboo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-code-to-track-changes-in-workbook.500810/&ved=2ahUKEwijkKe_k-DnAhU9ILcAHUYBCMAQFjAJegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw2VfF8gURvhLXbFWu7Z7uIT&cshid=1582203532202)

> hope in the code you may find functions or they may help you in tracking

Comment: it helped a lot, thank you very much. it makes it so i can track changes without sharing the document.